# How to $sum value on two collections in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sum, aggregate

My English is not good, hope you understand my question.
I'm newbie, i trying use some value from 2 collection.

I have two collections:

Collection 1:

```
{
 _id: "61241ad82fcb9a369e59868a",
 "name": "aaaa",
 "products": [{
     "_id": "611803232eeaf825336e26c4",
     "name": "products1",
     "pricePolicy": { "costPrice": 10 }
   }, 
   {
     "_id": "611803232eeaf825336e26c5",
     "name": "products2",
     "pricePolicy": { "costPrice": 10 }
  }]
}, 
{
 _id: "61241ad82fcb9a369e59868b",
 "name": "bbb",
 "products": [{
    "_id": "611803232eeaf825336e26c4",
   "name": "products1",
   "pricePolicy": { "costPrice": 20 }
  }, 
  {
   "_id": "611803232eeaf825336e26c5",
   "name": "products2",
   "pricePolicy": { "costPrice": 10 }
  }]
}
```

And collection 2:

```
{
  "_id": "61179c8d4ef00f31df195223",
  "name": "zzzz",
  "listProduct": [
     {
       "id": "611803232eeaf825336e26c4",
       "name": "products1",
       "costPrice": 100,
     },
     {
       "id": "611803232eeaf825336e26c6",
       "name": "products3",
       "costPrice": 10,
      }
     ]
},
```

How to $sum `costPrice` from two collection and sort product by value?
result follow:

```
   {
  _id: 611803232eeaf825336e26c4,
    name: products1,
      totalCollection1: 30,
        totalCollection2: 10,
          total: 40
}
{
  _id: 611803232eeaf825336e26c5,
    name: products2,
      totalCollection1: 20,
        totalCollection2: 0,
          total: 20
}
{
  _id: 611803232eeaf825336e26c6,
    name: products3,
      totalCollection1: 0,
        totalCollection2: 10,
          total: 10
}
```

Comment: You need to write an aggregation query for this. `$lookup` aggregate stage allows 'joining' two collections on a specific field. Then you can use `$group` to perform the sum on the `name` field.

Comment: {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'salesquotations',
                let: { product: '$_id' },
                pipeline: [
                  {
                    $match: {
                      $expr: {
                        $and: [
                          { $eq: ['$products._id', '$$product'] },
                          { $gt: ['$createdAt', fromDate] },
                          { $lte: ['$createdAt', toDate] },
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
as: 'salesquotation',
}, },

Comment: { $unwind: { path: '$salesquotation', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
            { $unwind: { path: '$salesquotation.products', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: '$_id',
                totalSale: { $sum: '$salesquotation.products.pricePolicy.costPrice' },
                name: { $first: '$name' },
              },
            },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: '$_id',
                name: { $first: '$name' },
                totalSale: { $first: '$totalSale' },
},
},

Comment: { $addFields: { total: { $sum: ['$totalSale'] } } },
            { $sort: { total: -1 } },
            { $skip: 0 },

Comment: i try lookup Collection Product to collection1 but not working.

Comment: @prasad_ can u help me?

Comment: @CuongTQ Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Comment: I solved my problem, thanks everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this aggregate query, and it works as desired. I had used the data from your question post and the result is at the bottom:

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$products" },
{ $sort: { "products._id": 1 } },
{ $group: { 
    _id: "$products._id", 
    productName1: { $first: "$products.name" }, 
    total1: { $sum: "$products.pricePolicy.costPrice" } 

} },
{ $group: { _id: null, productSummary1: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
{ $lookup: {
     from: "coll2",
     pipeline: [],
     as: "products2"
}},
{ $unwind: "$products2" },
{ $unwind: "$products2.listProduct" },
{ $sort: { "products2.listProduct.id": 1 } },
{ $group: {
    _id: "$products2.listProduct.id", 
    productSummary1: { $first: "$productSummary1" },
    productName2: { $first: "$products2.listProduct.name" }, 
    total2: { $sum: "$products2.listProduct.costPrice" }
}},
{ $group: { _id: null, 
    productSummary1: { $first: "$productSummary1" }, 
    productSummary2: { $push: { "_id": "$_id", "productName1": "$productName2", "total2": "$total2" } }
}},
{ $project: { products: { $concatArrays: [ "$productSummary1", "$productSummary2" ] } } },
{ $unwind: "$products" },
{ $group: { 
    _id: "$products._id", 
    productName: { $first: "$products.productName1" },
    total1: { $sum: "$products.total1"  },
    total2: { $sum: "$products.total2" },
    total1a: { $push: "$products.total1" },
    total2a: { $push: "$products.total2" },
}},
{ $project: { productName: 1, total1: 1, total2: 1, total: { $sum: { $concatArrays: [ "$total1a", "$total2a" ] } } } },
{ $sort: { total: -1 } }
])
```

*The output:*

```
{
        "_id" : "611803232eeaf825336e26c4",
        "productName" : "products1",
        "total1" : 30,
        "total2" : 100,
        "total" : 130
}
{
        "_id" : "611803232eeaf825336e26c5",
        "productName" : "products2",
        "total1" : 20,
        "total2" : 0,
        "total" : 20
}
{
        "_id" : "611803232eeaf825336e26c6",
        "productName" : "products3",
        "total1" : 0,
        "total2" : 10,
        "total" : 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `$unwind` deconstruct the `products` array
- `$group` by null and construct the `products` array with required fields
- `$lookup` with collection 2

  - `$unwind` deconstruct the `listProduct` array
  - `$project` to show required fields
- `$project` to concat both collections array in single field `products`
- `$unwind` deconstruct the above `products` array
- `$group` by `_id` means product id and get the total sum of price for both the collection
- `$ifNull` to check if the value is null then it will return 0
- `$addFields to add new field total to get total of both collections price
- `$sort` by total in descending order

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      col1: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$products._id",
          name: "$products.name",
          totalCollection1: "$products.pricePolicy.costPrice"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "col2",
      pipeline: [
        { $unwind: "$listProduct" },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: "$listProduct.id",
            name: "$listProduct.name",
            totalCollection2: "$listProduct.costPrice"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "col2"
    }
  },
  { $project: { products: { $concatArrays: ["$col1", "$col2"] } } },
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$products._id",
      name: { $first: "$products.name" },
      totalCollection1: { $sum: { $ifNull: ["$products.totalCollection1", 0] } },
      totalCollection2: { $sum: { $ifNull: ["$products.totalCollection2", 0] } }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { total: { $sum: ["$totalCollection1", "$totalCollection2"] } } },
  { $sort: { total: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YNMLn6Y7G-1)